# Meaning of 'roll' in 'I have all my grass to roll'

Tags: meaning

> ‘Oh, I am so sorry,’ said Hans, ‘but I am really very busy to-day.  I
>   have got all my creepers to nail up, and all my flowers to water, and
>   all my grass to roll.’

The above is a part of *Devoted Friend* by Oscar Wilde.

In the dictionary it could be used two opposite ways:

1. wrap something round and round upon itself
2. To spread, compress, or flatten by applying pressure with a roller

Which one would be proper for the above sentence?

Comment: Are you saying that you think Mr Wilde used the word *roll* inappropriately in his writing, or are you asking which definition goes with what he wrote?

Comment: It's meaning #2. A cylinder of concrete, or a hollow cylinder of metal filled with water, is rolled over a lawn to make the ground even/smooth and pack grass seed into the dirt so it does not blow away.

Comment: Recipe for turf: seed and roll for 400 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the tradition in England to "roll" the sod in a lawn at regular intervals.  "Rolling" consisted of pushing a weighted roller (a drum filled with water, with a handle to facilitate pushing) over the lawn, to press the sod down to be nice and smooth and tight.  I understand that this is still done to some degree on "estate" lawns in the UK.
[image]

Comment: Rolling the soil with a lawn roller helps to establish newly seeded grass, ensuring the seeds make good contact with the soil and don't blow away. Once the lawn is established, periodic rolling firms the ground and makes damaged areas more evident, so those spots can be re-seeded.

Comment: It's not just UK.

Comment: Yeah, rolling is used in the US, to get the lawn established (and on golf courses, to make the greens nice and flat), but is not done "periodically" on the vast majority of lawns.  I heard of a UK groundskeeper who was asked how he got the lawn so smooth and dense.  "Simple," he replied.  "Just roll the a lawn once a week.  For 50 years."